# ssh: connect to host ********* port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall

I have Ubuntu 22.04 newly installed on my laptop. I am trying to connect to a remote server and getting the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host  ********* port 22: Connection timed out
```

I tried some solutions which include,

- ping the IP address
- adding the IP address to the firewall using sudo ufw
- installing ssh and openssh
  However, nothing seems to work. I'd be thankful if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: is the service "sshd" running on the machine you are trying to reach?

Comment: I checked if sshd is running on my laptop with **ps aux | grep sshd**...it seems that it is running with root 5653. However, idk if sshd is running on the machine that I am trying to reach. I can access the server using google shell so I think the problem is in my connection.

Comment: It doesn't really have much to do with your local machine.  Are you sure that port 22 is the correct port that the remote system is listening on? It's the default port but often changed to something arbitrary.  If you portscan the remote machine with nmap, do you see TCP port 22 as open, closed or filtered?  Have portscanned from a few different networks to see if the results are consistent?  Have you talked to the owner of the remote machine to verify what port you're supposed to be using, have they verified SSHD is running and that there's not any firewalling that would block you?